# Creating Webservice in.NET 4.0 to consume JSON data in android

Tags: android, .net, json

I have no code with me. I need to create a webservice that can fetch data from database, in JSON format. This data will be consumed in android. I don't know where to start from. It would be great if anyone could help, show me the way.

Comment: Start with some Java tutorials on webservices. Then look at database integration, and the Android part shouldn't be too hard once you can do the other bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are proficient in .net, it's not a big deal to do that. At Android side you just do this way.

```
List<NameValuePair> parmeters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));// These are the namevalue pairs which you may want to send to your php file. Below is the method post used to send these parameters

  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); // You can use get method too here if you use get at the .net side to receive any values.

  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

  is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

At your .net side, `you extract the data and send back the result by encoding it in json format. While at the android side again, you can get the input stream as shown above. From that input stream, you can get the json data.`

For more details see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635395/how-to-send-variable-from-php-to-an-android-app/13638686#13638686). If you still want any sources, then I might edit my answer with some sources. Hope this helps.