# How do i send Java variable php file?

Tags: java, php, android, eclipse

I am currently trying something very simple, I want to send only one variable to the php web server.

I've seen many examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635395/how-to-send-variable-from-php-to-an-android-app) one. But when I try to insert them with my current code it returns errors, and I am not sure how I need to handle this.

My current Java (part) code looks like this:

```
    public void mahGPSbutton() {


    Button myGPS_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPS_button);
    myGPS_button.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    myGPS_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                                                                              //#
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); //#
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {                                                      //#
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double MyLat = location.getLatitude();
                    double MyLong = location.getLongitude();
                    double MyAlt = location.getAltitude();
                    String MyProvider = location.getProvider();
                    float MyAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                    double alt=MyAlt;
                    String url = "www.[IP of my web server]/[A Folder]/Binder.php";

                }
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}                                    //#
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}                                                             //#
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                //#
            };                                                                                                                //#
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                                                                                                              //#
        }                                                                                                                     //#
    }); 
}
```

I know...there is nothing that is ready to send, but like I said I have tried many ways and they all give some errors, even if there was no error, I would still be unable to send them to the php file.

Anyway, for the php code I've deciced to keep it simple, so its like:

```
<?php
    echo 'I have received this parameter: '.$_GET['MyLat'];
?>
```

Now, there is (if I'm right) only problems with the java code, what should I do to make this work? or could I get some ideas that may help?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

you can send in your String url

something like that

```
String url = "www.[IP of my web server]/[A Folder]/Binder.php?myLat="+ MyLat;
```

Then you can make the GET request

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

if you have a special chars in some var  you need to encode the var

```
String myLatEnconde =  URLEncoder.encode(MyLat);
```

Or do it like this

```
String url = "www.[IP of my web server]/[A Folder]/Binder.php?myLat="+ URLEncoder.encode(MyLat);
```

Comment: hello.
May i ask why you used Binder.php"?myLat=" ?
i would like to understand why i should put that, thx.

Comment: because you are catching the variables with $_GET array so i deduced you are sending a get request and those request must be in the url