# How to send data to server database from android app

Tags: php, android

I'm using a recyclerview to display the list of player. I added a click listener to recycler view. I want to send `player_name` to server side using PHP. If someone clicks on one of the items. But I don't know why somehow the code doesn't work. Whenever I execute the code, it just jumps to previous activity.

Below is the android code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick_TeamAdapter(int position) {
        TeamItems clickedItem = list_items.get(position);

        String url = "http://www.prasaurus.com/trial_db_php/post_data.php";

        player_name = clickedItem.getPlayer_name();
        player_id = clickedItem.getPlayer_id();
        player_DOB = clickedItem.getPlayer_DOB();

        final List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player_name",player_name));
        //parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player_id",player_id));
        //parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player_DOB",player_DOB));

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for server side php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "prasaurus.com";
$username = "prasauru_fand";
$password = "MYPASSWORD";
$dbname = "prasauru_trial_db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$Name=$_POST['player_name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO trial_data (player_name)
VALUES ('{$Name}')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Logcat :

```
Process: com.prasaurus.app.team_selection, PID: 21966
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:370)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
        at com.prasaurus.app.team_selection.Team1SquadSelection.onItemClick_TeamAdapter(Team1SquadSelection.java:191)
        at com.prasaurus.app.team_selection.TeamAdapter$Viewholder$1.onClick(TeamAdapter.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21193)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

I'm using Onclick listener on RecyclerView Adapter to select the item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send variable from php to an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635395/how-to-send-variable-from-php-to-an-android-app)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I've already tried that still now working :(

Comment: What is the result of your debugging work? Are any of the Exceptions catched? Is a http connection established? Is the php script itself ok and running? Did you set breakpoints in android to see how far you get? ...?

Comment: tell me any authentic player name ?

Comment: @Jeff PHP code is working good, there are no exceptions. I guess it is unable to establisHTTPtp connection. Please check the edit. I've added my logcat. It shows error in my recyclerViewAdapter Class OnClick function

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan Ronaldo -_-

Comment: have you given network permission in manifest

Comment: there is an exception: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan Yes, I have added permission to manifest file.

Comment: try  this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Sending List and Receiving variables there ?

Comment: I use HttpURLConnection for successful data transfer, if you like, i will post my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay So `NetworkOnMainThreadException`  comes when you try to do some thing on Main Thread which should be on Background thread.
 You can transfer your code to AsyncTask . error will be resolved.

```
public class backgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    String url = "http://www.prasaurus.com/trial_db_php/post_data.php";

    player_name = clickedItem.getPlayer_name();
    player_id = clickedItem.getPlayer_id();
    player_DOB = clickedItem.getPlayer_DOB();

    final List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player_name",player_name));
    //parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player_id",player_id));
    //parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player_DOB",player_DOB));

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
}
```

For calling this method. use

```
new backgroundTask().execute();
```